# How to display HTML Table structure in RDLC Report

Tags: report, rdlc

I am using RDLC report of ASP.net. The report is working fine and exported to PDF as well.

The issue i have faced is that, In some columns data is saved with HTML table tags such as

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width: 123px">
asdads</td>
<td style="width: 123px">
asdad</td>
<td style="width: 123px">
asda</td>
<td style="width: 123px">
asdd</td>
<td style="width: 123px">
asdadsa</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 123px">
1</td>
<td style="width: 123px">
2</td>
<td style="width: 123px">
3</td>
<td style="width: 123px">
4</td>
<td style="width: 123px">
5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 123px">
6</td>
<td style="width: 123px">
7</td>
<td style="width: 123px">
8</td>
<td style="width: 123px">
9</td>
<td style="width: 123px">
10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 123px">
11</td>
<td style="width: 123px">
12</td>
<td style="width: 123px">
13</td>
<td style="width: 123px">
14</td>
<td style="width: 123px">
15</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 123px">
16</td>
<td style="width: 123px">
17</td>
<td style="width: 123px">
18</td>
<td style="width: 123px">
19</td>
<td style="width: 123px">
20</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 123px">
21</td>
<td style="width: 123px">
21</td>
<td style="width: 123px">
21</td>
<td style="width: 123px">
2</td>
<td style="width: 123px">
32</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 123px">
65</td>
<td style="width: 123px">
54</td>
<td style="width: 123px">
87</td>
<td style="width: 123px">
54</td>
<td style="width: 123px">
&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

But the problem is RDLC does not interpret HTML Table Tags. The entire Table tags are displayed instead of Tabular structure. If i checked the Interpret HTML tags as style option in Place holder properties, HTML table tags are not displayed by the text is displayed as text in single row

Please help to to display tabular structure in RDLC report. .

Answer (score 0):

Since RDLC Does not support table tag So you can apply the technique as follows:
Step 1: Drag and drop Rectangle from Toolbox.
Step 2: Drag and drop 4 Text Box from Toolbox Label with column Name as like Table Header Row.
Step 2: Drag and drop each 4 Text Box from Toolbox Label with value as like table row.Iterate this drag and drop you want to create row.